# Connected components of a vector space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $U$ an open subset of $E$. I must prove that the connected components of $U$ are open and that, if $E$ is separable, we can enumerate the connected components of $U$.

For the first part, i think i've managed to prove. We know that every normed vector space is connected, and every open ball in this vector space is connected. I'm the definition, the connected component is the union of every connected subsets. So, i have a union of open sets and we are done. But i don't know where can i start with the second question.

Comment: Do you mean $U$ is an open subset?  A subspace is connected.

Comment: yes! I will edit. Sorry.

Comment: What have you tried for the second question?

Comment: Given the first part, the second part is fairly immediate from the definition of separable. You just need to turn an enumeration of the countable dense subset of $E$ into an enumeration of the connected components of $U$, which are open and disjoint...

Comment: So, can i assume that my first part is right?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct, but I think it is not properly elaborated.

1. *We know that every normed vector space is connected.* Correct, but irrelevant.
2. *Every open ball in this vector space is connected.* Correct, it is the key for your result.
3. *The connected component is the union of every connected subsets.* This statement is too imprecise. You can say that the connected component $C$ of a point $x$ in a space $X$ is the union of all connected subsets of $X$ containing $x$.
4. *So, i have a union of open sets and we are done.* Correct, but the context should be explained more precisely.

Here is a suggestion.

Let $C$ be a connected component of $U$ and $x \in C$. There exists an open ball $B(x)$ such that $x \in B(x) \subset U$. Thus $B(x)$ is a connected subset of $U$ containing $x$ and therefore $B(x) \subset C$. Hence $C  = \bigcup_{x \in X}B(x)$ is open.

The second question has been answered by Karl's comment. This is how it works.

Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $E$. Consider a connected component $C_\alpha$ of $U$ and pick $x_\alpha \in C_\alpha$. We have $x_\alpha \in \overline D$, thus each open neigborhood of $x_\alpha$ intersects $D$. In particular we can pick $d_\alpha \in C_\alpha \cap D$. Hence $C_\alpha$ is the connected component of $d_\alpha$ in $U$. Since there are only countably many points in $U \cap D$, there are only countably many connected components of $U$.